# Laravel SelectRaw Query Not Executing

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm having an issue where my query listed below won't execute on our live server (it should return a data set of ~2940 records as of the time I'm writing this, the query executes fine when run via MySQL).

It doesn't throw any error whatsoever, the query simply does not execute and the code never reaches anything **after** the query. This only happens on our live/production server, and doesn't happen on our development and local environments (perhaps because the data set is so much smaller?)

The intention of this function is to take this data and spit it into a CSV file that is then handed back to the user, hence the header setting.

```
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
    
    $filename = "ORDERS-" . date("m-d-Y") . ".csv";    

    $query_result = Order::selectRaw("orders.id AS \"Order_ID\", orders.distributor_id AS \"Distributor_ID\", orders.gross_total AS \"Gross_Total\", IF( orders.multiple_card_id != 0, \"Yes\", \"No\" ) AS \"Group_Order\", IF( orders.payment_plan_id != 0, \"Yes\", \"No\" ) AS \"Recurring_Order\", orders.name AS \"Order_Name\", order_statuses.name AS \"Order_Status\", order_statuses.id AS \"Order_Status_ID\", DATE(orders.created_at) AS \"Order_Date\", order_shipment_methods.name AS \"Shipping Method\", addresses.line1 AS \"Address_Line_1\", addresses.line2 AS \"Address_Line_2\", addresses.line3 AS \"Address_Line_3\", addresses.city AS \"City\", addresses.postal_code AS \"Address_Postal_Code\", states.name AS \"Address_State\", countries.name AS \"Address_Country\"")
    ->leftjoin("addresses", "addresses.id", "=", "orders.address_id")
    ->leftjoin("states", "addresses.state_id", "=", "states.id")
    ->leftjoin("countries", "addresses.country_id", "=", "countries.id")
    ->leftjoin("order_statuses", "orders.order_status_id", "=", "order_statuses.id")
    ->leftjoin("order_shipments", "order_shipments.order_id", "=", "orders.id")
    ->leftjoin("order_shipment_methods", "order_shipments.shipping_method_id", "=", "order_shipment_methods.id")
    ->whereRaw("YEAR(orders.created_at) = \"" . date("Y") . "\"")->get();
```

Any pointers on to why this might not be working? I'm lost because there's nothing in an error log or anything like that.

Comment: Make sure you check all error logs. For example out of memory errors will not be logged in the laravel log and will only be logged in the vhost configured log or the log of the default vhost (depending on which point the memory ran out)

Comment: Bypass the quotes, you can pass the date in as a bound parameter. `->whereRaw("YEAR(orders.created_at) = ?", [date('Y')])`. Also remove the quotes around your column aliases, they aren't needed

Comment: @apokryfos looks like you were right -- it was a memory issue, makes sense since it only started happening with the data set. i corrected this by loading the data in chunks of 1000 rows each to keep the memory freed up. works fine now! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being due to a memory overflow issue.

I didn't want to just increase the memory for this job, so I was able to fix this by making the query fetch 1000 rows at a time instead of asking it to grab everything at once. It's slower because of the multiple database calls, but it will get the job done.

```
    $i = 0;
    $size = 1000;

    do
    {
        $query_result = Order::selectRaw("orders.id AS \"Order_ID\", orders.distributor_id AS \"Distributor_ID\", orders.gross_total AS \"Gross_Total\", IF( orders.multiple_card_id != 0, \"Yes\", \"No\" ) AS \"Group_Order\", IF( orders.payment_plan_id != 0, \"Yes\", \"No\" ) AS \"Recurring_Order\", orders.name AS \"Order_Name\", order_statuses.name AS \"Order_Status\", order_statuses.id AS \"Order_Status_ID\", DATE(orders.created_at) AS \"Order_Date\", order_shipment_methods.name AS \"Shipping Method\", addresses.line1 AS \"Address_Line_1\", addresses.line2 AS \"Address_Line_2\", addresses.line3 AS \"Address_Line_3\", addresses.city AS \"City\", addresses.postal_code AS \"Address_Postal_Code\", states.name AS \"Address_State\", countries.name AS \"Address_Country\"")
        ->leftjoin("addresses", "addresses.id", "=", "orders.address_id")
        ->leftjoin("states", "addresses.state_id", "=", "states.id")
        ->leftjoin("countries", "addresses.country_id", "=", "countries.id")
        ->leftjoin("order_statuses", "orders.order_status_id", "=", "order_statuses.id")
        ->leftjoin("order_shipments", "order_shipments.order_id", "=", "orders.id")
        ->leftjoin("order_shipment_methods", "order_shipments.shipping_method_id", "=", "order_shipment_methods.id")
        ->whereRaw("YEAR(orders.created_at) = ?", [ date("Y") ])->offset( $i * $size )->limit( $size )->get();
     

        //now for each query result, we'll pop the data into the csv
        foreach( $query_result as $q )
        {
            $data_set = [];
            foreach( $q as $key => $value ) { array_push( $data_set, $value ); }
            fputcsv( $dl, $data_set );
        }
        

        $i++;
    } while ( count($query_result) == $size );
```